# Unity TMPro text to float parsing not working, Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a game in Unity where I need to convert a TextMeshProUGUI text into a float, but for some reason this code:

```
float num = float.Parse(inputText.text);
```

Gives me this error:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) (at <d4cde64232cf45659d86aafa597faa77>:0)
System.Number.ParseSingle (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value,
System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at <d4cde64232cf45659d86aafa597faa77>:0)
System.Single.Parse (System.String s) (at <d4cde64232cf45659d86aafa597faa77>:0)
```

Why is this happening? How is a string with a simple number (i used 1 as an example) not the right format? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you checking to make sure `inputText.text` has a non-null value?

Comment: Yes, i have this line in a function called by the EndEdit event on the input box. I have not done null checking now but i am sure. I also did a Debug.Log("|" + inputText.text + "|"); to make sure that it doesn't have any wierd stuff, but nothing. Maybe it has different encoding? How could i check and correct that?

Comment: Do a Debug.Log(inputText.text); right before your parse so you can see what its actually trying to parse. If that doesn't illuminate you as to what the problem is, edit your post letting us know what the output was.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says "FormatException"

you can fix the problem by playing with the float format itself

```
float num = float.Parse(inputText.text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

I hope that fixed the problem you are having

you can check this link for more info about it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Single_Parse_System_String_